# Reducer - add new element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

I have this store:

```
const initialActors = {
    list: 'Actor\'s lists',
    actors: [
        {
            name: 'Angelina Jole',
            involved: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Bratt Pitt',
            involved: false
        },
    ]
}
```

I have a reducer to add a new actor to my store:

```
const actors = (state = initialActors, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_NEW':
            return {
                ...state.list,
                actors: [
                    ...state.actors,
                    action.name,
                    action.involved
                ]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I have a action creator too but it doesn't important. I dispatch that and display my state:

```
store.dispatch(addNew({name: "Hello", involved: true}) ); // I have this action creator
console.log(store.getState()
```

`console.log` displays very difficult object with letters like: `{0: "A", 1: "c"}`. What is wrong?

@Edit
I tryed change ...state.list to state list like this:

```
const actors = (state = initialActors, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_NEW':
            return {
                state.list,
                actors: [
                    ...state.actors,
                    action.name,
                    action.involved
                ]
            }


        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

but I have this error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
>   Similiar situation I have if I tryed modify actors array:

```
case 'ADD_NEW':
    return {
        ...state.list,
        actors: [
            ...state.actors,
            {
                action.name,
                action.involved
            }

        ]
    }
```

Error message is this same but point at action object (action.name).

Comment: Added the solution kindly check :) let me know if you need any further clarifications on the same

Comment: again you are doing ....state.list, as it is string it will spread each characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

state.list is a string, and you are trying to spread it

```js
let a = 'name'
let c = {...a}
console.log(c)
```

run the above code snippet so you will be able to understand it

and for adding new object you need to update the reducer as follows

```
                ...state,
                actors: [
                    ...state.actors,
                    {  
                       name: action.name,
                       involved: action.involved
                    }
                ]
```

so the above code will spread all the existing properties in the state and then you spread all the current actors and add a new object as shown above

Update

Since you are passing as

```
store.dispatch(addNew({name: "Hello", involved: true}) );
```

here the payload is an object so you can directly use that one

so in action it will be object which has two props one is

- type
- the payload you have send it

  ```
                  ...state,
                  actors: [
                      ...state.actors,
                      action.payload
                  ]
  ```

Sample Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59580383-so-adding-new-element-reducer-vkgyn)

Comment: but I I tryed this `state.list` (without ...) i have the error: unexpected token (.), expected (,)

Comment: again you are doing ....state.list, as it is string it will spread each characters, in the object you are having value where is the key ?

Comment: try using the above way exactly same and try

Comment: Almost. App works with little problem. Objects which was created before in store works correctly but new actor has one extra object inide. Normal store look like this: `actors: {name: 'Something', invloved: true}`but your code create object which look like this: `actors: {name: {name: 'Something', involved: true}}`

Comment: let me check it, i will try mimc that one with sample snippet of code, give me some time

Comment: try using the updated way and let me know, put a console.log(action), and check what is the property where the data lias

Comment: I have added a working codesandbox , check and let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer, you are mistakenly spreading `state.list`. Since it is a string, you are getting all the letters. You should spread the `state` there. Because, you want to keep your `state`, other than `actors` array. This is why you spread the whole `state` and keep the `list` (with others if there would be).

Also, you are adding your item wrong, it should be an object.

```
const actors = (state = initialActors, action) => {
  const { name, involved } = action;

  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_NEW":
      return {
        ...state,
        actors: [
          ...state.actors,
          {
            name,
            involved
          }
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small mistake what you did, you need to add as an object with 2 properties like `[...state.actors, { action.name, action.involved }]` instead of what you did.

From [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)'s documentation:

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

Like this:

```
const actors = (state = initialActors, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_NEW':
            return {
                ...state,
                actors: [
                    ...state.actors,
                    {  
                       name: action.name,
                       involved: action.involved
                    }
                ]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Consider the following:

```js
var array = [
  {  
    name: 'someone',
    involved: false,
  }
];

console.log([...array, { name: 'hello', involved: true }]);
```

I hope this helps!